# proj4js convert long, lat to x,y by axis by meters

Tags: coordinates, convert, latitude-longitude, proj4js

Can anyone provide right projections for proj4js convert long, lat to x,y by axis by meters?
Here is my projections:

> const fromLatLongProjection = '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84
> +units=degrees +axis=neu';
>
> const toXYProjection = '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0
> +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs'

I am not sure if I have to use from 'EPSG:4326' to 'EPSG:3857' or any other definition. Please help. Here is code that I wrote:

> const firstProjection = '+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84
> +units=degrees +axis=neu'; const secondProjection = '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs';
>
> function transformBbox(bbox) {
> return [...proj4(firstProjection, secondProjection,[55.929425, 23.310854])] }
>
> console.log(transformBbox());

Here is pictures of what I want to achieve:
[image: LAT LONG TO X Y IN METERS]

[image: X Y TO IN METERS TO LAT LONG]

Result what I get is:

> 6226035.111360585, 2669654.709007479

As you see both coordinates close to the point of required result, but not exactly correct. Please help. Why is that? What projections I should use??

Comment: Should I use EPSG:3785 ? Its seems that its deprecated

Comment: ```const firstProjection = '+title=WGS 84 (long/lat) +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees';
const secondProjection = '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs';``` EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 doesnt work too